# Curator version discrepancy between shell and cron

Tags: elasticsearch, cron, elasticsearch-curator

I have recently upgraded elasticsearch-curator from 3.4.1 to 4.1.0.  I have also created a new configuration file and action files required to do the same things I was doing with 3.4.1.  What happens, is that when cron runs the scripts, it shows up as 3.4.1.  If I sudo run the script manually, it shows up as 4.1.0

I've removed the apt package and migrated to the pip package.  This is the only thing that I can think of that could be causing this.

Here's the script, which would run from cron.daily (temporarily moved to cron.hourly for testing, which has irresponsibly been set to run every minute):

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/curator --version
/usr/local/bin/curator --config /etc/curator/curator.yml /etc/curator/actions/01-nightly-close
/usr/local/bin/curator --config /etc/curator/curator.yml /etc/curator/actions/02-nightly-optimize
```

I am able to run the script as sudo and the version number shows 4.1.0:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/curator
curator, version 4.1.0
```

If I let cron run the job, it shows version 3.4.1:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/curator
curator, version 3.4.1
Error: no such option: --config
Error: no such option: --config
run-parts: /etc/cron.hourly/curator exited with return code 2
```

Also, when I run `which curator`, it points to `/usr/local/bin/curator`

EDIT: To answer untergeek's question, here are the contents of `/usr/local/bin/curator`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from curator.curator import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: What are the contents of `/usr/local/bin/curator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working-- I ended up purging all instances of curator from my node, both pip and apt versions, then running the following commands per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/installation.html:

```
wget -qO - https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://packages.elastic.co/curator/4/debian stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/curator.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-elasticsearch-curator
```